# `yq` seems cannot work with XML with just one element

Tags: xml, yq, xq

I am using the following the command to extract data from an XML file:

```bash
yq -p=xml '.resources.string[] | [.+@name, .+content] | join("|")' sample.xml
```

With an input XML file like:

```xml
<resources>
    <string name="String-1">String 1</string>
    <string name="String-2">String 2</string>
</resource>
```

The command works fine with the output:

```bash
String-1|String 1
String-2|String 2
```

But if the input XML file contains only one element:

```xml
<resources>
    <string name="String-1">String 1</string>
</resource>
```

The output is just two empty lines.

The input file is read properly and one element, with one attribute and one content, is properly identified, but somehow the values are dropped. If not doing the join operation with the same one element input XML file:

```bash
yq -p=xml '.resources.string[] | [.+@name, .+content] ' input.xml
```

The output is:

```bash
[]
[]
```

It looks like a bug but it could also be some settings I missed. Any workaround or fix?

I am using `yq` version `v4.34.2` installed with ***brew*** on MacOS (Intel) 13.4.1

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem here is that in your second example, `yq` treats `resources.string` as a dictionary rather than an array. Compare the output of `yq -pxml .resources` between the first example:

```
string:
  - +content: String 1
    +@name: String-1
  - +content: String 2
    +@name: String-2
```

And the second example:

```
string:
  +content: String 2
  +@name: String-2
```

So for your second example, you can ask for:

```
$ yyq -pxml -oyml '.resources.string|[.+@name, .+content]|join("|")' < sample2.xml
String-2|String 2
```

---

The second example is treated like a dictionary because that's how `yq` handles an element with distinct child elements, like:

```
<cat>
  <says>meow</says>
  <legs>4</legs>
  <cute>true</cute>
</cat>
```

Which becomes:

```
cat:
  says: meow
  legs: "4"
  cute: "true"
```

Looking through [the docs](https://mikefarah.gitbook.io/yq/usage/xml) there doesn't appear to be a way to enforce the array interpretation when there's a single element.

Comment: That's a workaround. Thanks.

As you mentioned, it would be nice to add an option to force it to be array, or convert the result to a one-element array when it sees the expression `[]`

Answer (score 1):

As @larsks pointed out, the one-element case is treated as the element itself rather than an array containing that one element. That's (sadly) the most prevalent way for various converter tools to interpret and transcode XML into structures like YAML or JSON. And neither `yq` from [mikefarah/yq](https://github.com/mikefarah/yq) nor `xq` from [kislyuk/yq](https://github.com/kislyuk/yq) make this behavior optional.

You can, however, include a switch in your filter. Check for the input's `type`, and only iterate if it is an array:

```bash
yq -p=xml '.resources.string | (select(type == "!!seq") | .[]) // . | [.+@name, .+content] | join("|")'
```

With `xq`, you can do the same but making use of the `arrays` [shortcut](https://jqlang.github.io/jq/manual/#arrays,objects,iterables,booleans,numbers,normals,finites,strings,nulls,values,scalars) (which resolves to selecting by type) provided by `jq` proper:

```bash
xq -r '.resources.string | arrays[] // . | [."@name", ."#text"] | join("|")'
```